# Could not find matching close tag for "<%" in node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js for Array.foreach()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, foreach, ejs

I new to node and mongoDB and here I am trying to build a to-do-list. My project folder *beautiful-todolist_mongoDB* has a views folder containing *list.ejs* and other .ejs files.

**Error** : Could not find matching close tag for "<%".
at /Users/xxx/Documents/beautiful-todolist_mongoDB/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:740:19
at Array.forEach ()
at Template.generateSource (/Users/xxx/Documents/beautiful-todolist_mongoDB/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:730:15)
at Template.compile (/Users/xxx/Documents/beautiful-todolist_mongoDB/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:585:12)
at Object.compile (/Users/xxx/Documents/beautiful-todolist_mongoDB/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:396:16)
at handleCache (/Users/xxx/Documents/beautiful-todolist_mongoDB/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:233:18)
at tryHandleCache (/Users/xxx/Documents/beautiful-todolist_mongoDB/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:272:16)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/xxx/Documents/beautiful-todolist_mongoDB/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:489:10)
at View.render (/Users/xxx/Documents/beautiful-todolist_mongoDB/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
at tryRender (/Users/xxx/Documents/beautiful-todolist_mongoDB/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)

My **list.ejs**

```
<%- include("header") -%>
<div class="box" id="heading">
  <h1><%=listTitle%></h1>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <!-- <% for (var i=0; i<listItems.length ; i++) { %>
          <div class="item">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <p><%= listItems[i].name %></p>
          </div>
          <% } %> -->
  <% listItems.forEach(function(item){ %>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <p><%= item.name %></p>
  </div>
  <% }) %>
  <form class="item" action="/" method="post">
    <input
      type="text"
      name="task"
      id="task"
      placeholder="New Item"
      autocomplete="off"
    />
    <button type="submit" name="list" value="<%" ="listTitle%">>+</button>
  </form>
</div>
<%- include("footer") -%>
```

I don't understand why it shows that I have a missing closing tag for *<%*. The same code is working when I use the for loop but forEach is not working.
Also, I tried reading the error and looking for the root cause but it does not say if I have an error in *beautiful-todolist_mongoDB/node_modules/views/list.ejs* rather it says I have a missing closing tag in *beautiful-todolist_mongoDB/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:740:19*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo at your button:

```
<button type="submit" name="list" value="<%" ="listTitle%">>+</button>
```

You are not closing the ejs tags here. It should be like this:

```
<button type="submit" name="list" value="<%= listTitle %>">+</button>
```

Comment: It worked, thank you!! 
Missed such a small thing but I am not sure why it was not shown in the error description that which line had the error in my list.ejs file. It was confusing as it pointed error in some node_module/ejs/lib.... file and so I never looked anywhere else